# Disable visual studio message

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is it possible to disable this message from visual studio build?

[image]

I simply don't want to see those messages, but I still want to see warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! At the top, go to Tools -> Options. Click on the Projects and Solutions tab. Click on the Build and Run tab. Change the output verbosity to quiet. This will still display warnings.

Comment: Sorry my fault, i dont want to see just  : EterBaseLIB ->   Build started.    But compile file i want to see. :( I think this is not possible.